# Secure backup between two NAS servers

Tags: debian, nas

Problem:
I have two NAS servers, both running Debian, located on two different addresses. Each has an album of pictures, which are both several 100gb.

What i would like is to set up a secure backup function that backs up the pictures on one NAS to the other one, and vice versa.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a program which can do this out of the box which i can install and use without too much hassle.

Requirements:

Traffic must be encrypted

Must only back-up the file once pr change (Should remember or check which files are backed up)

It would also be nice if it could be started and stopped so it only runs during the night time.

If anyone knows of such a program, then i would very much like to know. I have stared myself blind googling for hours.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible with [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) over ssh.

Comment: I'm guessing it requires installation on both machines?

Comment: Yes. 
rsync is a very common tool and maybe already installed. If not it should be easy to install with the package management: "apt-get install rsync"

Comment: I ended up using rsync over SSH. It works very well and can be easily set up to only back up changed files. Cron is used to invoke at night. Setup time: 20 minutes.